# What XCOM in-game descriptions are totally broken?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

The text for the MEC-carried EMP states exactly the opposite of what it does.  The decoy device description would lead one to try it before activating a pod, but it only works after.  What other descriptions are shockingly terrible?

Last I checked, at least these two are still present in the otherwise excellent Long War mod.  Perhaps if we had a list we could convince those devs to address...

Comment: Are the descriptions wrong even in the game without the Long War mod?

Comment: @Chippies yes, at least the EMP device.  Can't say I ever (successfully) used a decoy until LW, but vaguely recall trying and failing.

Comment: @Kikanaide: I remember a Beaglerush video where he used decoys before having spotted the enemy (he deduced their whereabouts). When he finally made contact, all nearby enemies were at the decoy's location or close to it.

Comment: Is this question a good fit for this site? It seems chatty and open ended, and you're asking for a list of answers rather than a single one that can be accepted. While a definitive answer with all bad descriptions may be possible, would it not be better to compile this list somewhere more suited to threaded discussion, like a forum?

Answer (score 1):

I have complaints as well about the descriptions of various utils, items and modifications. A lot of them are just vague and some of them are not even close to telling the player what it does. Mostly the gene mods display these vague descriptions. If you ask me they should overhaul the whole description system.

To give an example:

**Mimetic Skin**

*"Confers the ability to change skin pattern to match cover"*, this does not tell me anything about the skill specifically.

*"When the soldier moves to high cover, enemies without special capabilities will not target the soldier"*, high cover? So half cover on a higher location counts? No they actually mean full cover. And what kind of special abilities do the aliens need to render this skill useless?

Reading the first 2 lines of the description confused me and left me with even more questions.